# multiple divs with fixed position and scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, html, fixed, sticky

I have 4 divs and I want to scroll down and cover all those divs. But... keeping the current div with fixed position on top of the browser

This is working great only scrolling down. But when I scroll up fails.

You can check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rtSKj/ for a demo

This is the js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(scrollY>=500){
            $('#block2').css({'position': 'fixed', 'margin-top': 0});
            $('#block3').css({'margin-top': '1000px'});
        }

        if(scrollY>=1000){
            $('#block3').css({'position': 'fixed', 'margin-top': 0});
            $('#block4').css({'margin-top': '1500px'});
        }

    });

});
```

note: the height of the divs is: 500px;

Should I consider the scroll direction to fix the behavior?

Comment: It seems to work without the jQuery. Or maybe I am just miss-understanding your question.

Comment: When you say "it fails" when you scroll up, what behavior are you expecting vs what you're seeing?

Comment: yes Kris i forgot to link jquery. but is in the fiddle :)

Comment: when i scroll down it should do the opposite. div 4 over div 3.... then div 3 over div 2... then div 2 over div 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'reset' the position and margin-top.

```
if(scrollY<500) {
  $('#block2').css({'position': 'relative', 'margin-top': '500px'});
}
if(scrollY<1000) {  
  $('#block3').css({'position': 'relative','margin-top': '1000px'});
}
```

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rtSKj/14/

Comment: upps sorry. something is wrong. the block3 "appears" only when block2 hits the top. but block3 need to be right down block2... i think this happen with block4 too. what could be wrong??