# scroll through divs stacked on each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Long story short: I'd like to scroll through full-screen divs. Looking at previous question I found this which is quite close to what I need but with some changes. 
    https://jsfiddle.net/naqk671s/

Instead of having the div #1 fixed and the #2 landing on the top of it, I'd like to have the #1 going up and revealing the #2.

My confidence with jQuery is not so big, so I tried to change some values but I just made it worst. do you think is possible to achieve the result with few changes or should I just start from scratch?

```
under = function(){
    if ($window.scrollTop() < thisPos) {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: ""
        });
        setPosition = over;
    }
};

over = function(){
    if (!($window.scrollTop() < thisPos)){
        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0
        });
        setPosition = under;
    }
};
```

To make my self more clear, what I'm trying to achieve is basically the opposite of the fiddle I've posted. If you scroll all the way down and than start to scroll up that will be the effect I'd like to achieve but upside down.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

---

**Update:**
 After comment, request became clearer, look these examples...

---

**Pure CSS:** https://jsfiddle.net/9k8nfetb/

- Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

---

**jQuery**: https://jsfiddle.net/kajwhnc1/

- Reference: [multiple divs with fixed position and scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653602/multiple-divs-with-fixed-position-and-scrolling)

---

Another **jQuery**: https://jsfiddle.net/6da3e41f/

- Reference: [How to make div fixed after you scroll to that div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850271/how-to-make-div-fixed-after-you-scroll-to-that-div)

---

**Snippet**

```js
var one = $('#one').offset().top;
var two = $('#two').offset().top;
var three = $('#three').offset().top;
var four = $('#four').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {

  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (currentScroll >= 0) {
    $('#one').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '0',
    });
  } else {
    $('#one').css({
      position: 'static'
    });
  }

  if (currentScroll >= two) {
    $('#two').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '26px',
    });
  } else {
    $('#two').css({
      position: 'static'
    });
  }

  if (currentScroll >= three) {
    $('#three').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '52px',
    });
  } else {
    $('#three').css({
      position: 'static'
    });
  }

  if (currentScroll >= four) {
    $('#four').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: '78px',
    });
  } else {
    $('#four').css({
      position: 'static'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 200%;
}

#one,
#two,
#three,
#four {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#one {
  top: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#two {
  top: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#three {
  top: 200%;
  background-color: #0a0;
}

#four {
  top: 300%;
  background-color: #a05;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div id="one">ONE</div>
  <div id="two">TWO TWO</div>
  <div id="three">THREE THREE THREE</div>
  <div id="four">FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time. I try your fiddle but it doesn't look like it's working to me. 
It's like all the div are one after each other, and not behind. Would it help if i sketch something in PS? maybe is clearer?

Comment: @Antonio after comment, request became clearer, please make sure the code now matches your need ;)

Comment: @Antonio anyone of these examples helped you?

Comment: I just noticed your answer, thanks. Sorry but I was AFK for a bit. Unfortunately I think I didn't make my self clear.  So this [pen](https://codepen.io/tonytozoo/pen/GaLVdj) I did by my self, is what I wanted to achieve. maybe having a look at it will help you understanding.
anyhow I have 2 new problems now!! :D should I  ask here or open a new request:
1. mobile issues: the 'scrollTop()' doesn't work in mobile, I should use 'scrollTo(x,y)' but I don't know how to do this with variables;
2. overall the code is too buggy, if you scroll to fast eveything is broken; 
any idea how to fix this?